# Why are domain level structured from right to left?

Tags: dns, structure, subdomain

Why are domains structured from right to left (from top level element on)?

```
www.google.com
```

instead of

```
com.google.www
```

I don´t know any other situation, where the top-level element is on the right.
It´s always

```
parent/child/sub-child
```

Just interested.

Comment: Maybe this can help you understanding why they are structured like that: http://domain.me/how-domain-names-work/

Comment: Thanks. But I know how they work and why they are structured like that. What I mean, is just the direction they are written.

Comment: @FranzDeschler I speculate it might be because DNS was inspired by earlier directory services (like X.500) which also used a right-to-left format (e.g. `cn=John Smith,ou=People,dc=Company,dc=com`), in which case you should find out why X.500 did it that way :)